# Show overlay only once on page entrance (not route change). HowTo?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, gatsby, grommet

So I try to have an overlay over my gatsby site for about a split second to let it load the correct breakpoint in the back. How can I achieve this?

So I set an Interval and some State to load the Overlay and make it disappear after an interval. But the problem after each page reload the overlay appears again. I have no state management like redux and I need the Overlay to only appear after every refresh or entrance from external links but not clicking on internal links.

I've tried `useEffect` with only render on the mount but this does not do the trick as internal link changes will trigger a remount

I figured out that I could use the Browser API onInitialClientRender. But I don't understand how a value generated in there can be accessed outside of the gatsby-browser.js. In general, I have issues understanding how to use these APIs.

customHooks.js

```
export function useInterval(callback, delay) {
  const savedCallback = useRef()

  // Remember the latest callback.
  useEffect(() => {
    savedCallback.current = callback
  }, [callback])

  // Set up the interval.
  useEffect(() => {
    function tick() {
      savedCallback.current()
    }
    if (delay !== null) {
      let id = setInterval(tick, delay)
      return () => clearInterval(id)
    }
  }, [delay])
}
```

Layout.js

```
let [loadingIndicator, setLoadingIndicator] = useState(true)
const delay = 500

useInterval(() => {
  setLoadingIndicator(false)
}, delay)
```

So the expected result would be a way to tell on the initial client render to set a state which tells the Overlay to be rendered and after this one render the state should change to disable the render of the overlay.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Solution:**

Using gatsby's ability to change the static index.html file. [Customize Index.html in Gatsby][1]

Adding a custom div to the generated html.js

> html.js:

```
   <div
      key={`loader`}
      id="___loader"
      style={{
        alignItems: "center",
        backgroundColor: "#F2F2F2",
        display: "flex",
        justifyContent: "center",
        position: "absolute",
        left: 0,
        top: 0,
        right: 0,
        bottom: 0,
        zIndex: 1,
      }}
   >
      <LoaderSVG width="50%" />
   </div>
```

and in gatsby-browser.js:

> gatsby-browser.js:

```
export const onInitialClientRender = () => {
  document.getElementById("___gatsby").style.display = "block"
  setTimeout(function() {
    document.getElementById("___loader").style.display = "none"
  }, 200)
}
```

The ***next step*** is to check whether all the data is loaded and add a dynamic value instead of the timeout.

Comment: You say it is not working then immediately follow with saying you figured out a working answer. Which is it?

Comment: So its the Solution. The Div you add to the Index.html. You can check how it looks and feels on spoortracking.ch

Answer (score 0):

I did something like this.

I copied the default html from .cache directory and pasted into src directory.

I used following command:

`cp .cache/default-html.js src/html.js`

in the html.js file, I noticed following codes:

```
import React from "react"
import PropTypes from "prop-types"

export default function HTML(props) {
  return (
    <html {...props.htmlAttributes}>
      <head>
        <meta charSet="utf-8" />
        <meta httpEquiv="x-ua-compatible" content="ie=edge" />
        <meta
          name="viewport"
          content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no"
        />
        {props.headComponents}
      </head>
      <body {...props.bodyAttributes}>
        {props.preBodyComponents}
        <div
          key={`body`}
          id="___gatsby"
          dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{ __html: props.body }}
        />
        {props.postBodyComponents}
      </body>
    </html>
  )
}

HTML.propTypes = {
  htmlAttributes: PropTypes.object,
  headComponents: PropTypes.array,
  bodyAttributes: PropTypes.object,
  preBodyComponents: PropTypes.array,
  body: PropTypes.string,
  postBodyComponents: PropTypes.array,
}
```

I put SVG loader which is an image and few lines of CSS:

So complete code like this:

```
import React from "react"
import PropTypes from "prop-types"
import LoaderSVG from './img/loader.svg'

export default function HTML(props) {
  return (
    <html {...props.htmlAttributes}>
      <head>
        <meta charSet="utf-8" />
        <meta httpEquiv="x-ua-compatible" content="ie=edge" />
        <meta
          name="viewport"
          content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no"
        />
        {props.headComponents}
      </head>
      <body {...props.bodyAttributes}>
        {props.preBodyComponents}
        <div
              key={`loader`}
              id="___loader"
              style={{
                alignItems: "center",
                backgroundColor: "#F2F2F2",
                display: "flex",
                justifyContent: "center",
                position: "absolute",
                left: 0,
                top: 0,
                right: 0,
                bottom: 0,
                zIndex: 1,
              }}
           >
              <img src={LoaderSVG} alt="" width="150"/>
        </div>
        <div
          key={`body`}
          id="___gatsby"
          dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{ __html: props.body }}
        />
        {props.postBodyComponents}
        <script
          dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{
            __html: `
                setTimeout(function() {
                    document.getElementById("___loader").style.display = "none"
                }, 200)
            `,
          }}
        />
      </body>
    </html>
  )
}

HTML.propTypes = {
  htmlAttributes: PropTypes.object,
  headComponents: PropTypes.array,
  bodyAttributes: PropTypes.object,
  preBodyComponents: PropTypes.array,
  body: PropTypes.string,
  postBodyComponents: PropTypes.array,
}
```

And then restart Gatsby and it works.

Comment: also working nice i belive. but i stick with my solution works like a charm

Comment: @TheWeeezel, I am getting error using your solution: ReferenceError: exports is not defined on exports.onInitialClientRender. Are you using old version of Gatsby? I am using the 2.23.3. But when I use this way it works: ```export const onInitialClientRender = () => {
  setTimeout(function() {
    document.getElementById("___loader").style.display = "none"
  }, 200)
}```

Comment: yes this now leads to an error. ive updated it accordingly. thanks for letting me know.