# Noticeable load lag with SVG styling in Gatsby. How could I optimize the loading?

Tags: html, css, reactjs, svg, gatsby

[image: Lag]

I'm using the oninitialclientrender from Gatsby the Gatsby API and @TheWeeezel's method from [Show overlay only once on page entrance (not route change). HowTo?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57188179/show-overlay-only-once-on-page-entrance-not-route-change-howto) to use a React component as a loading screen for my site. The issue is that there is a noticable delay on the initial loading of the svg's styling needed for positioning and fills. I've tried inline styling instead of loading the styling using a css file, but it still causes the same delay. Here is my code from my custom html.js file.

```
<div
      id="___loader"
      key={`loader`}
      style={{
        background: "#0F2027",
        height: "100%",
        width: "100%",
        margin: "0",
        padding: "0",
      }}
    >
      <LoadingAssets></LoadingAssets>
    </div>
```

Here is the code from my gatsby-browser.js file too.

```
exports.onInitialClientRender = () => {
  console.log("loaded")

  setTimeout(() => {
    document.getElementById("___loader").style.opacity = "0"
    console.log("loader changed.")
  }, 1000)
  setTimeout(() => {
    document.getElementById("___loader").style.display = "none"
    console.log("loader removed")
  }, 2000)
  setTimeout(() => {
    document.getElementById("___gatsby").style.display = "block"
  }, 2000)
  setTimeout(() => {
    document.getElementById("___gatsby").style.opacity = 1
  }, 3000)
}
```

How could I optimize this better so that the delay isn't noticeable on the svg styling?

Comment: Starting to take some of the sub-components out of the LoadingAssets component and implementing more inline styling on the html.js page. It seems to be helping a little.

Answer (score -1):

Instead of using a React component to render the SVG, you could just put the SVG in your custom `html.js` file. Something like this:

```
// html.js

export default () => {
    return (
        <html {...this.props.htmlAttributes}>
            <head>
                <meta charSet="utf-8" />
                <meta httpEquiv="x-ua-compatible" content="ie=edge" />
                <meta
                    name="viewport"
                    content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no"
                />
                {this.props.headComponents}
                <style>
                    #___loader { /** YOUR CSS FOR THE LOADER */ }
                </style>
            </head>
            <body {...this.props.bodyAttributes}>
                <div id="___loader">
                    <svg ...>
                        <path ... />
                        <path ... />
                    </svg>
                </div>
                {this.props.preBodyComponents}
                <div
                    key={`body`}
                    id="___gatsby"
                    dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{
                        __html: this.props.body,
                    }}
                />
                {this.props.postBodyComponents}
            </body>
        </html>
    )
}
```

If this is not an option for you, another option would be to hide the site entirely (using CSS) and show it back using the `useEffect` hook (or componentDidMount) in your SVG component. So the site would be hidden until the SVG component is mounted.